# Android Image Visibility

Tags: android

so have created a couple of buttons, fadeIn and fadeOut, to fade an image of a country in and out, respectively. The fadeOut button by default is unclickable until fadeIn has been pressed and when the fadeIn button is pressed it fades the image in and then sets the visibility to 0 to stop it from disappearing again.

My problem is that when I press the fadeOut button and, once it has faded out, I set the visibility to 1 to make it invisible but still present, but the image still reappears. Why is this? I followed the same steps as in my first button and the image remains on screen fine.

Whats the problem?

Comment: can you post some Code here plz , and one more thing , did you set the Visibility of your image to View.GONE ????

Comment: Cheers houcine - when I created the image in the XML file I set the visibility to invisible - so it took up space on the screen but was still present. But I also solved it by setting the animation alpha level once the fadeout animation has ended.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use integer values, but instead use the constants provided by the view class

you should be using:

.setVisibility(VIEW.INVISIBLE); or setVisibility(VIEW.GONE);

If you really want to use integer values (for some crazy reason) they are not 0 and 1 but rather it is:

0 - visible

4 - invisible

8 - gone

Not sure why these are multiples of 4.